# Empty Burndown Chart

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm working with Visual Studio Team Services. I'm trying to build an example project with few sprints inside. I have declared all tasks in my Backlog Items, but I have no idea why:

- Despite I declare effort for each task, I can see it only in the column
  of the parent folder.
- Burndown chart is empty. Can I somehow set previous date in the tasks? I need to fill my burndown chart with some data.

  [image]
  [image: Sprint Screen]
  [image: Single Task]
  [image: Empty burnout]

Comment: Do you clear it under Daniel's help?

Answer (score 3):

The iteration is in the future. It won't show a burndown chart until 7/3.

Also, it's called a "burndown" chart, not a "burnout" chart. "Burnout" has a very different meaning in English. :)

Comment: haha sorry! Hope its mac autocompleter fault, but anyway I'm sitting with this problem for a while already, so it may be the reason also. Is there some way to set different dates to each task? Becouse even if i set sprint start and end time on January 2017, it still doesnt work.

Comment: @DanZawadzki Tasks don't have dates. Sprints have dates. You don't get a burndown chart for sprints that are in the past (because they're done), nor do you get them for sprints that are in the future (because they haven't started yet). A burndown chart only applies to a sprint that's in progress.